# SQL joining two tables with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql I am using myphpadmin for my database I am trying to combine two tables that has common value in column for my project. I would really appreciate any suggestions or help. Thanks in advance.

I have two tables named;

```
 TableA:

 id      Name    Section    c_status

 1a      aika    Section1   Active
 2s                         Inactive
```

---

```
TableB:

id     PR_id     Name     Section    

111    2s      laika     Section2   
222    2s      Bes       Section3
```

---

My desire output is;

```
 id   Name   Section     c_status

 1a   aika   Section1    Active
 2s   laika  Section2    Inctive
 2s   Bes    Section3    Inctive
```

I tried to use SELECT * FROM TableA,TableB WHERE TableA.id=TableB.PR_id

However I got wrong output.
I would really appreciate advice. Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output you did get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `UNION` and `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != ''
UNION
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id
```

The first select is for the data that have empty value in `Name` field. The second select is to combine two tables with related id.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are great!